# Border shifting linear-gradient background

Tags: html, css, border, linear-gradients

I have a `div` with a `background` defined as `linear-gradient`, and an almost transparent `border` on top of it. It should paint correctly, but the rendering is broken.

[image: Broken linear-gradient background with transparent border]

[Here is the associated CodePen](https://codepen.io/ghivert/pen/vYrqXjM).

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.gradient-background {
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, #681c2e 0%, #232a6c 49.48%);
  height: 80px;
  border: solid 20px rgba(248, 251, 255, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient-background"></div>
```

Do you know how to fix this with CSS? It behaves consistently on Chrome and Firefox. Is it an expected behavior in the spec of CSS and HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rgba(248, 251, 255, 0.1);` is what causes the issue.

Use `background-origin: border-box;` and it will work fine.

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.gradient-background {
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, #681c2e 0%, #232a6c 49.48%);
  height: 80px;
  border: solid 20px rgba(248, 251, 255, 0.1);
  background-origin: border-box;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="gradient-background"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

For more information about this, check this [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-origin).